# Isenthalpic process and heat involved

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry

[image]

In the given question as in photo we are asked to calculate heat involved in isenthalpic process. Since isenthalpic means ΔH = 0 and we know  enthalpy is the heat content at constant pressure.As in the question, pressure is constant then why answer not option (a) but (b). I must be wrong in Terminology. I think heat involved, heat content and heat change are different things. What do you think am i right? What does these terms mean then?

Comment: Thank you. Actually I didn't read the question properly as I just noticed. It was mentioned it is an irreversible process and given process is occurring against constant external pressure which doesn't mean that the pressure of the system during expansion is constant.

Answer (score 1):

The pressure of the ideal gas in the initial state was not 1 bar; it was higher than 1 bar.  In this irreversible process, the external pressure was dropped suddenly from the higher initial gas pressure to 1 bar at time zero, and held at that value during the entire expansion.  But the final pressure of the gas, at 1 bar, was not equal to its initial pressure.  So the heat was not equal to the change in enthalpy; the gas did not undergo an isobaric process.

For an ideal gas, we know that, if $\Delta H$ was zero, we know that the gas temperature was constant.  That means that the change in internal energy was equal to zero.  So, from the first law, we have that $$\Delta U=Q-W=0$$or $$Q=W$$